# Multiplication and division produce decimal with different scale, why?

Tags: mysql, operators, division

When I query data from MySQL, I noticed this behavior:

```
select 1 / 100; 
-- 0.0100

select 1 * 0.01;
-- 0.01
```

I try to run they in different machine, but get the same result: division produces 4 decimal places, multiplication produces 2 decimal places.

Can someone tell me why they different?

Comment: Division of integers produces decimal which have 4 digits after decimal point by default. Multiplication uses datatype with precise which is a sum of operands precise which is 0+2=2 digits - for example, `SELECT 0.5*0.02;` will give the result with 1+2=3 digits.

Comment: ok，I try to run `1.00*0.01` and get the result is `0.0100`. Now I know that multiplication's rules.And how can i change the division's default number digits after decimal point? Can you teach me,Thanks.

Comment: `CAST( @x / @y AS DECIMAL(m,n) )`

Comment: I know this way,and i try this first time to solve my question.Can it setting in mysql? If it can, we needn't use cast in sql everytime.

Comment: Use explicit cast to datatype needed always. If you do not want to be unpleasantly surprised somewhen...

Comment: OK,I see,Thanks for your help.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for resulting datatype [are described here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html):

> In division performed with `/`, the scale of the result when using two
>   exact-value operands is the scale of the first operand plus the value
>   of the `div_precision_increment` system variable (which is 4 by
>   default).

So we have:

```sql
SELECT 1    / 100   -- 0.0100
SELECT 1.0  / 100   -- 0.01000
SELECT 1.00 / 100   -- 0.010000

SELECT 1   / 100.0  -- 0.0100
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it can help me a lot.